# ExpressionMetadataProvider in .net core 3.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

Migrate .net core 2.2 to 3.1, I have trouble with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures".
In this code, ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression not support in .net core 3.1.

```
public static IHtmlContent CustomTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(
        this IHtmlHelper<TModel> htmlHelper,
        Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression,
        object htmlAttributes
    )
    {
        var member = expression.Body as MemberExpression;
        var stringLength = member.Member
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof(StringLengthAttribute), false)
            .FirstOrDefault() as StringLengthAttribute;

        var expresionProvider = htmlHelper.ViewContext.HttpContext.RequestServices
   .GetService(typeof(ModelExpressionProvider)) as ModelExpressionProvider;

        var modelExplorer = ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression(expression, htmlHelper.ViewData, htmlHelper.MetadataProvider);

        ModelMetadata metadata = modelExplorer.Metadata;
        string htmlFieldName = expresionProvider.GetExpressionText(expression);
        string labelText = metadata.DisplayName ?? metadata.PropertyName ?? htmlFieldName.Split('.').Last();
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is about .NET Core 3.1; but I stumbled upon this because I had the same problem in .NET 6

Snippet to get the actual value

`HttpContext.RequestServices.GetRequiredService<IModelExpressionProvider>().CreateModelExpression(viewData, expression).ModelExplorer.Model;`

Answer (score 1):

> Migrate .net core 2.2 to 3.1, I have trouble with "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures". In this code, ExpressionMetadataProvider.FromLambdaExpression not support in .net core 3.1.

From ASP.NET Core 3.0, some `pubinternal` APIs are updated to be truly internal, which seems cause your above issue.

And as mentioned in [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/12643#issuecomment-515702458), it offers [`ModelExpressionProvider`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/c565386a3ed135560bc2e9017aa54a950b4e35dd/src/Mvc/Mvc.ViewFeatures/src/ModelExpressionProvider.cs) in 3.0+ that's available from DI and expose the method(s) that can return an instance of `ModelExpression` which is a superset for `ModelExplorer` that `ExpressionMetadataProvider` returns.